# How to use Google Drive URL for Facebook Graph API

Tags: api, facebook, drive

I try using Facebook Graph API with the upload photo feature.

I'm hosting the photo from Google Drive and the URL has the format: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=IMAGE_ID

But I received the error after I make the first request:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Missing or invalid image file",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 324,
    "error_subcode": 2069019,
    "is_transient": true,
    "error_user_title": "Image Required",
    "error_user_msg": "Make sure your Page post includes an image that can be used in an ad.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AMlEwvLBvptiO2kZc1DRnRN"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
I really appreciate your the answers.

Comment: What request are you making?

Comment: I have to make a POST request. I using Explore Tools on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: So what request are you making?

Comment: _"and the URL has the format"_ - and that for sure returns an image directly? Not a _page_ that shows the image, or something like that?